# Free ASP.NET WYSIWYG control needed

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

I need a free ASP.NET WYSIWYG control, which allows me to edit full HTML page.
I tried FreeTextBox, RichTextBox and others, but they remove <html>, <head>, <body> and etc tags when I switch to Design View.

I googled a workaround and found two opened topics on the FreeTextBox forum dated 2005 and 2007 with no answer.

http://freetextbox.com/forums/thread/8351.aspx
http://freetextbox.com/forums/post/10368.aspx

Is there a real working WYSIWYG which satisfy my requirements?

Answer (score 3):

Try the asp.net version of fckeditor: http://ckeditor.com/

It's free and open source

Comment: I tried a demo on http://ckeditor.com/demo. It removes html, head, body, doctype and etc.

Comment: That's something you have to configure

Answer (score 2):

I use the TinyMCE editor at work and on my blog. The editor includes a fullpage plug-in for use in editing whole documents.

You can find the editor here:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

And documentation on the plugin here:

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/fullpage

Comment: Used it on my blog as well.  Little ramp up time for me, but it did what I needed it to do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact TinyMCE do what I need, it allows to edit full HTML code. Clear TinyMCE is JS. It is too compleceted to use it in ASP.NET: every time I have to configure it via web.config, copy js files to a project, reference dll to a project with ASP.NET control from TinyMCE .NET package.
I wonder if nobody have created a really good solution based on TinyMCE for ASP.NET yet.

Any other suggestions?